# Lambda function in variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to get rid of the overload function by using a Lambda or forwarding the arguments some how but it does not even compile. Why can't I do this? What alternatives are there?

I really don't want to use the overload function at all. I know what I'm doing is wrong but there has to be a way?

```
int maximum(int n)   //Trying to not have to use this.. I want to get rid of this :l
{
    return n;
}


template<typename... Args>
int maximum(int n, Args... args)
{
    return std::max(n, [&args...](int n){return n;});  //tried using a lambda instead of maximum(args...);
}
```

I also tried:

```
template<typename... Args>
int maximum(int n, Args... args)
{
    return std::max(n, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Also, why is (does not compile):

```
template<typename... Args>
int maximum(int n, Args... args)
{
    return std::max(n, []{return 0;});
}
```

different from (compiles):

```
template<typename... Args>
int maximum(int n, Args... args)
{
    return std::max(n, 0);
}
```

The first doesn't compile but the second certainly does.. :S

I use all of the above like: `std::cout<<maximum(1, 2, 3, 7, 2, 5);`

Comment: All other things being equal, the ultimate difference between the last two snippets is the difference between `[] { return 0; }` and `0`. Can you make sense of the difference between those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
template<typename... Args>
int maximum(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::max({std::forward<Args>(args)...});
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << maximum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

Comment: Wow.. Never thought I'd see a solution. Can you tell me why that works? Also, why does it work only with those curly brackets around the void and the forward?

It also seems to work without the void().. but why?

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: Thanks for letting me know, it seems all you need is the curly braces. The curly braces are needed because [std::max](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) takes an `std::initializer_list<T>`.

Comment: Omg.. Ahahaha I've been trying for more than an hour with it and didn't realize it was just curly braces. Thumbs up to you sir. LOL I couldn't help but laugh after noticing it after your comment.

Answer (score 1):

How about skipping the lambda and just writing:

```
template <typename T>
const T& maximum ( const T& t ) { return t; }

template <typename T, typename... Args>
const T& maximum ( const T& t, Args... args ) {
    return std::max ( t, maximum ( std::forward<Args>(args)... ));
    }
```

Comment: Because I was trying to get rid of calling maximum like you did for the std::max parameter. I didn't want to have to write the first function you have.. aka the one that returns t.